# Add factor variable to repeated measurements of individuals and their mate

Tags: r, dataframe, match, repeat, r-factor

I am working with paired animals (male and female) of several species and have repeated measurements at several life stages.
Here is the type of data frame I am working with:

```
> ID <- rep(c(seq(from=1, to=4), seq(from=5, to=8)), times=2)
> partner <- rep(c(seq(from=4, to=1), seq(from=8, to=5)), times=2)
> stage<- c(rep("juvenile", 8), rep("adult", 8))
> sex<- rep((rep(c("male", "female"), each=2)), times=4)
> species<-rep(c("a", "b"), each=4, times=2)
> df<-data.frame(ID, partner, stage, sex, species)

 ID partner    stage    sex species
1   1       4 juvenile   male       a
2   2       3 juvenile   male       a
3   3       2 juvenile female       a
4   4       1 juvenile female       a
5   5       8 juvenile   male       b
6   6       7 juvenile   male       b
7   7       6 juvenile female       b
8   8       5 juvenile female       b
9   1       4    adult   male       a
10  2       3    adult   male       a
11  3       2    adult female       a
12  4       1    adult female       a
13  5       8    adult   male       b
14  6       7    adult   male       b
15  7       6    adult female       b
16  8       5    adult female       b
```

I want to add a factor variable with a different level for each individual male within species (e.g. Individual with ID=1 always has factor level A, ID=2 has factor level B, etc.), and then I want their partner to have the same factor level (ID=10 has factor level A, ID=9 has factor level B, etc.). Here is what it should look like (this example is incredibly simple):

```
> df
   ID partner    stage    sex species WANTED
1   1       4 juvenile   male       a      A
2   2       3 juvenile   male       a      B
3   3       2 juvenile female       a      A
4   4       1 juvenile female       a      B
5   5       8 juvenile   male       b      A
6   6       7 juvenile   male       b      B
7   7       6 juvenile female       b      A
8   8       5 juvenile female       b      B
9   1       4    adult   male       a      A
10  2       3    adult   male       a      B
11  3       2    adult female       a      A
12  4       1    adult female       a      B
13  5       8    adult   male       b      A
14  6       7    adult   male       b      B
15  7       6    adult female       b      A
16  8       5    adult female       b      B
```

Important to note:

- In the real dataset, the number of individuals is not the same among species, such that if I take letters as factor levels, species x with 4 individuals will have the factor levels from A to D, while species y with 6 individuals will have the factor levels from A to F.
- I want the factor levels to start over when dealing with another species (in my example data frame, ID=1 has factor level A, and so does ID=11 because it is a different species).
- One given individual should have the same factor level at all stages (juvenile and adult)

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT**
Here is my real dataframe as shown with `dput`, with all its difficulties:
Sorry for its length! (not sure how to hide it in a dropdown).
To sum up what I want:

- a new factorial variable where each individual has its factor level, repeated across life stages
- two partners of a given pair have the same factor level
- factor levels repeat themselves among species (strains), for example BW has A1, A2, ... A8 and LL has A1, A2, ... A9

```
structure(list(ID = c(11489L, 11862L, 11539L, 11713L, 11271L, 
9225L, 11588L, 9906L, 11039L, 9717L, 11539L, 11713L, 11489L, 
11862L, 11403L, 11070L, 11271L, 9225L, 11039L, 9717L, 11588L, 
9906L, 12124L, 12021L, 12029L, 12126L, 12020L, 12030L, 12125L, 
10450L, 11371L, 11605L, 11327L, 11019L, 11741L, 11586L, 11740L, 
11585L, 10575L, 11855L, 11500L, 11403L, 11070L, 11539L, 11713L, 
11740L, 11585L, 11327L, 11019L, 11489L, 11862L, 12124L, 12021L, 
11371L, 11605L, 12631L, 12304L, 12303L, 10008L, 12630L, 12275L, 
12272L, 10007L, 12029L, 12126L, 12125L, 10450L, 11271L, 9225L, 
11588L, 9906L, 11039L, 9717L, 12020L, 12030L, 12910L, 11588L, 
9906L, 11039L, 9717L, 11539L, 11713L, 11271L, 9225L, 11403L, 
11070L, 12094L, 12095L, 11255L, 12390L, 11257L, 11740L, 11585L, 
11327L, 11019L, 11371L, 11605L, 12097L, 11611L, 12124L, 12021L, 
12029L, 12126L, 12125L, 10450L, 12020L, 12030L, 12110L, 12910L, 
12095L, 11740L, 11585L, 11255L, 12097L, 12390L, 11257L, 11611L, 
12094L, 12631L, 12304L, 12303L, 10008L, 11209L, 12630L, 12275L, 
11403L, 11070L, 12272L, 10007L, 12124L, 12021L, 11489L, 11862L, 
10744L, 11209L, 10575L, 12110L, 10744L, 11069L, 11827L, 11066L, 
12816L, 12415L, 12911L, 11248L, 12979L, 12746L, 12912L, 11855L, 
11500L, 11741L, 11586L, 12125L, 10450L, 11248L, 12979L, 12746L, 
12912L, 11066L, 12816L, 11643L, 11435L, 11069L, 11827L, 11327L, 
11019L, 11371L, 11605L, 12631L, 12304L, 12272L, 10007L, 12630L, 
12275L, 12910L, 12095L, 11209L, 10575L, 11643L, 11435L, 12110L, 
10744L, 12771L, 12388L, 11611L, 12094L, 11255L, 12097L, 12390L, 
11257L, 12272L, 10007L, 12303L, 10008L, 12631L, 12304L, 11855L, 
11500L, 12910L, 12095L, 11255L, 12097L, 11741L, 11586L, 12771L, 
12388L, 11069L, 11827L, 11066L, 12816L, 11611L, 12094L, 11855L, 
11500L, 11643L, 11435L, 12303L, 10008L, 11741L, 11586L, 11209L, 
10575L, 12746L, 12912L, 11248L, 12979L, 12630L, 12275L, 12110L, 
10744L, 12029L, 12126L, 11066L, 12816L, 12415L, 12911L, 11069L, 
11827L, 12771L, 12388L, 11643L, 11435L, 12746L, 12912L, 11248L, 
12979L, 12415L, 12911L, 12390L, 11257L, 12415L, 12911L, 12020L, 
12030L, 12771L, 12388L), Partner_ID = c(11862L, 11489L, 11713L, 
11539L, 9225L, 11271L, 9906L, 11588L, 9717L, 11039L, 11713L, 
11539L, 11862L, 11489L, 11070L, 11403L, 9225L, 11271L, 9717L, 
11039L, 9906L, 11588L, 12021L, 12124L, 12126L, 12029L, 12030L, 
12020L, 10450L, 12125L, 11605L, 11371L, 11019L, 11327L, 11586L, 
11741L, 11585L, 11740L, 11209L, 11500L, 11855L, 11070L, 11403L, 
11713L, 11539L, 11585L, 11740L, 11019L, 11327L, 11862L, 11489L, 
12021L, 12124L, 11605L, 11371L, 12304L, 12631L, 10008L, 12303L, 
12275L, 12630L, 10007L, 12272L, 12126L, 12029L, 10450L, 12125L, 
9225L, 11271L, 9906L, 11588L, 9717L, 11039L, 12030L, 12020L, 
12095L, 9906L, 11588L, 9717L, 11039L, 11713L, 11539L, 9225L, 
11271L, 11070L, 11403L, 11611L, 12910L, 12097L, 11257L, 12390L, 
11585L, 11740L, 11019L, 11327L, 11605L, 11371L, 11255L, 12094L, 
12021L, 12124L, 12126L, 12029L, 10450L, 12125L, 12030L, 12020L, 
10744L, 12095L, 12910L, 11585L, 11740L, 12097L, 11255L, 11257L, 
12390L, 12094L, 11611L, 12304L, 12631L, 10008L, 12303L, 10575L, 
12275L, 12630L, 11070L, 11403L, 10007L, 12272L, 12021L, 12124L, 
11862L, 11489L, 12110L, 10575L, 11209L, 10744L, 12110L, 11827L, 
11069L, 12816L, 11066L, 12911L, 12415L, 12979L, 11248L, 12912L, 
12746L, 11500L, 11855L, 11586L, 11741L, 10450L, 12125L, 12979L, 
11248L, 12912L, 12746L, 12816L, 11066L, 11435L, 11643L, 11827L, 
11069L, 11019L, 11327L, 11605L, 11371L, 12304L, 12631L, 10007L, 
12272L, 12275L, 12630L, 12095L, 12910L, 10575L, 11209L, 11435L, 
11643L, 10744L, 12110L, 12388L, 12771L, 12094L, 11611L, 12097L, 
11255L, 11257L, 12390L, 10007L, 12272L, 10008L, 12303L, 12304L, 
12631L, 11500L, 11855L, 12095L, 12910L, 12097L, 11255L, 11586L, 
11741L, 12388L, 12771L, 11827L, 11069L, 12816L, 11066L, 12094L, 
11611L, 11500L, 11855L, 11435L, 11643L, 10008L, 12303L, 11586L, 
11741L, 10575L, 11209L, 12912L, 12746L, 12979L, 11248L, 12275L, 
12630L, 10744L, 12110L, 12126L, 12029L, 12816L, 11066L, 12911L, 
12415L, 11827L, 11069L, 12388L, 12771L, 11435L, 11643L, 12912L, 
12746L, 12979L, 11248L, 12911L, 12415L, 11257L, 12390L, 12911L, 
12415L, 12030L, 12020L, 12388L, 12771L), Strain = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 
1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 
1L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 
4L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("BW", 
"IS", "LL", "PO"), class = "factor"), State = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L), .Label = c("Virgin", 
"Mated", "Expecting", "Parent"), class = "factor"), Sex = structure(c(1L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("F", 
"M"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("ID", "Partner_ID", "Strain", 
"State", "Sex"), row.names = c(NA, -256L), class = "data.frame")
```

So it would look like this:

```
       ID Partner_ID Strain  State Sex WANTED
1  11489      11862     BW Virgin   F     A1
2  11862      11489     BW Virgin   M     A1
3  11539      11713     BW Virgin   F     A2
4  11713      11539     BW Virgin   M     A2
5  11271       9225     PO Virgin   F     A1
6   9225      11271     PO Virgin   M     A1
7  11588       9906     PO Virgin   F     A2
8   9906      11588     PO Virgin   M     A2
9  11039       9717     PO Virgin   F     A3
10  9717      11039     PO Virgin   M     A3
11 11539      11713     BW  Mated   F     A2
12 11713      11539     BW  Mated   M     A2
13 11489      11862     BW  Mated   F     A1
14 11862      11489     BW  Mated   M     A1
15 11403      11070     PO Virgin   F     A4
16 11070      11403     PO Virgin   M     A4
17 11271       9225     PO  Mated   F     A1
18  9225      11271     PO  Mated   M     A1
19 11039       9717     PO  Mated   F     A3
20  9717      11039     PO  Mated   M     A3
```

Comment: maybe your example doesn't capture the complexity of what you'd like to do, but all I see is that column 'Wanted' is 'A' if 'ID' is odd and ''B' if even.  is that what you want?

Comment: Indeed, my example is overly simplified. My real ID numbers are not a number series, but rather random (e.g. 10577, 11088, ...). Thanks though.

Comment: Should say 'factor'/tag [tag:r-factor] instead of [tag:factorial], which means n!, which is not what you want

Answer (score 1):

Consider two `ave` calls for inline running grouped aggregation method. First, produces a raw group count factors by *Strain*, *State*, and *Sex* and second retains first factor for each *Partner_ID*. Then, wrap entire column with `as.factor` for needed type conversion.

Below `with` is a type of context manager to reference column names without repetitive data frame reference, `df$`.

```
# RUNNING GROUP COUNT
df$RAW_WANTED <- as.factor(paste0("A", with(df, ave(ID, Strain, State, Sex, 
                                                    FUN=seq_along))))

# RUNNING FIRST VALUE
df$WANTED <- as.factor(with(df, ave(as.character(RAW_WANTED), Partner_ID,
                                    FUN=function(x) head(x, 1))))

head(df, 20)
#       ID Partner_ID Strain  State Sex RAW_WANTED WANTED
# 1  11489      11862     BW Virgin   F         A1     A1
# 2  11862      11489     BW Virgin   M         A1     A1
# 3  11539      11713     BW Virgin   F         A2     A2
# 4  11713      11539     BW Virgin   M         A2     A2
# 5  11271       9225     PO Virgin   F         A1     A1
# 6   9225      11271     PO Virgin   M         A1     A1
# 7  11588       9906     PO Virgin   F         A2     A2
# 8   9906      11588     PO Virgin   M         A2     A2
# 9  11039       9717     PO Virgin   F         A3     A3
# 10  9717      11039     PO Virgin   M         A3     A3
# 11 11539      11713     BW  Mated   F         A1     A2
# 12 11713      11539     BW  Mated   M         A1     A2
# 13 11489      11862     BW  Mated   F         A2     A1
# 14 11862      11489     BW  Mated   M         A2     A1
# 15 11403      11070     PO Virgin   F         A4     A4
# 16 11070      11403     PO Virgin   M         A4     A4
# 17 11271       9225     PO  Mated   F         A1     A1
# 18  9225      11271     PO  Mated   M         A1     A1
# 19 11039       9717     PO  Mated   F         A2     A3
# 20  9717      11039     PO  Mated   M         A2     A3
```

Comment: That looks like a very elegant solution. The only issue is that I want each individual to keep their factor level across states (juvenile, adult), and your solution does not work on my dataset.

Comment: Not sure what you mean as this solution does render above desired result. Here `ave` uses *stage* as one grouping. Please post actual data (like `dput`) and desired result (better to show than tell).

Comment: Hmmm...not seeing much a difference between previous solution, except no longer using `LETTERS` and adjusting column names in `ave`. See edit (also your last two rows of desired result might need to be `A2`).

Comment: Nope, they need to be A3 because that was these individuals' factor level as "Virgin".

Comment: Then, how come the *BW Mated* group (rows 11-15) does not have `A3` having *Virgin* factors?

Comment: Because in this short example, there is no BW Virgin with A3 as a factor level.

Comment: See update now with two `ave` calls, keeping first raw calculated factor for each *Partner_ID*.

Comment: It looks great, I really thought it was it. Unfortunately, there are still some mistakes: some partners do not have matching factor levels (e.g. 12910 and 12095). Any idea why?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way of doing what I think you want in dplyr and a custom function.  This is not so elegant, but at least easier to understand:

```
library(dplyr)

# This will give you 260 unique factors
facSet <- paste0(rep(LETTERS,each = 10),rep(1:10,times = 10))

getFactor <- function(subsetDF) {
    key <- 1
    subsetDF$Factor <- NA
    for (i in 1:nrow(subsetDF)) {
        if (subsetDF$sex[i] == "male") {
            subsetDF$Factor[i] <- facSet[key]
            key <- key + 1
        }
    }
    for (i in 1:nrow(subsetDF)) {
        if (subsetDF$sex[i] == "female") {
            subsetDF$Factor[i] <- unique(subsetDF$Factor[which(subsetDF$partner[i] == subsetDF$ID)])[1]
        }
    }
    return(subsetDF$Factor)
}

df <- df %>% group_by(species) %>% mutate(Factor = getFactor(data.frame(ID,sex,partner)))
```

Output:

```
> df
# A tibble: 16 x 6
# Groups:   species [2]
      ID partner stage    sex    species Factor
   <int>   <int> <fct>    <fct>  <fct>   <chr> 
 1     1       4 juvenile male   a       A1    
 2     2       3 juvenile male   a       A2    
 3     3       2 juvenile female a       A2    
 4     4       1 juvenile female a       A1    
 5     5       8 juvenile male   b       A1    
 6     6       7 juvenile male   b       A2    
 7     7       6 juvenile female b       A2    
 8     8       5 juvenile female b       A1    
 9     1       4 adult    male   a       A3    
10     2       3 adult    male   a       A4    
11     3       2 adult    female a       A2    
12     4       1 adult    female a       A1    
13     5       8 adult    male   b       A3    
14     6       7 adult    male   b       A4    
15     7       6 adult    female b       A2    
16     8       5 adult    female b       A1
```

Note: if you need more than 260 unique male-female pairs, create a bigger *facSet*!

Comment: This is great, thanks! 
The only thing is that I would like the factor levels to repeat themselves between species. For example species x has A1, A2, A3 (three pairs), and species y has A1, A2, A3, A4, A5 (five pairs). Is it possible to tweek your code to do that?

Comment: Now the last problem: A given individual (e.g. male with ID=1) should have the same Factor level at all stages (i.e. juvenile AND adult). Thanks for your efforts!